# Batch File to create AnswerFile for Old Installer

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm having a problem getting "MOVE" to work in my script...
I'm making an answer file for an old installer and I can't get the move to actually work, it keeps saying that the path cannot be found, any ideas? I've been fighting this for a while and I think I'm at the point where I just need someone else to look at it.

```
@echo off

set /p exeLoc=Drop .EXE here: 
REM removing quotes
set exeLoc=%exeLoc:"=%
REM stripping filename from path
for %%i in (%exeLoc%) do set exeLoc=%%~dpi 
REM setting exeLoc   
set exePath=%exeLoc%

set /p fileName=Name of .ISS file to save: 
REM identifies if the filename contains the proper suffix (.iss)
if x%fileName:.iss=%==x%fileName% set fileName=%fileName%.iss
cls

echo.%exePath%
echo.%fileName%
echo.
echo.Please wait, this may take some time...

verify >nul
REM creates record of install
%exeLoc% -r
echo.

set moveDir=%exePath%\%fileName%
set fromDir=C:\Windows\setup.iss
verify >nul
move /Y %fromDir% %fileName%
echo.

IF '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='0' echo.Answer file moved to& echo.%moveDir%
IF NOT '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='0' echo.There as an issue moving& echo.%fromDir%& echo.to& echo.%moveDir%
pause
```

Comment: Have you examined the contents of `%exePath%` to confirm that it is a folder that exists on the specified drive and that it is a directory, not a file?
Does `C:\Windows\setup.iss` exist?

Comment: Did you intend to have `move /y "%fromDir%" "%moveDir%` instead of moving to `%fileName%`?  Does adding the quotation marks help?

Comment: @Tim Good catch, I was going the same route, but got sidetracked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I can help with this...

I once had an issue similar to what you're experiencing - it seems that you need to just rearrange how you handle your first variable.

I see that you first gather the full location+filename for your .exe, then you remove the quotes, but this is the problem, I think. Try your "for %%i" first.

While I was testing your script I got the same error at the end of it (I REM'd out your %exeLoc% -r, because it wasn't necessary to find your error). The issue was that for some reason it was giving me duplicated paths. I buried my location about 5 folders deep and in folders with spaces and numbers to try to recreate the dirtiest structure possible (C:\Test Test\first\2nd Folder\2013). I also saw fit to change directory to the location I was trying to write to. Not sure if that is imperative or not, but I found it to be good practice.

This is what I ended up having to change your first variable function to:

```
set /p exeLoc=Location of .EXE: 
set exePath=%exeLoc%
for %%i in (%exePath%) do set exePath=%%~dpi
set exePath=%exePath:"=%
cd %exePath%
```

The full Script is here:

```
@echo off

set /p exeLoc=Location of .EXE: 
set exePath=%exeLoc%
for %%i in (%exePath%) do set exePath=%%~dpi
set exePath=%exePath:"=%
cd %exePath%
set /p fileName=Name of .ISS file to save: 
if x%fileName:.iss=%==x%fileName% set fileName=%fileName%.iss
cls
echo.%exePath%
echo.%fileName%
echo.
echo.Please wait, this may take some time...
verify >nul
%exeLoc% -r
echo.
set moveDir=%exePath%\%fileName%
set fromDir=C:\Windows\setup.iss
verify >nul
move /Y %fromDir% %fileName%
echo.
IF '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='0' echo.Answer file moved to& echo.%moveDir%
IF NOT '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='0' echo.There as an issue moving& echo.%fromDir%& echo.to& echo.%moveDir%
pause
```